# creating baseline regression model with average and min values in python

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, regression, pandas-groupby, linear-regression

I want to compare results of my regression analysis with encoded categorical variables with two baseline models where the baseline predictions are specified as the average or min values of the groups. I've chosen Rsquare and MAE for comparison. Below is a simplified example of my code for illustration. It works in that it gives me an output which I think achieves my goal. Is this the correct and/or best way to do this?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split 
from sklearn import metrics

df = pd.DataFrame([['a1','c1',10],
                   ['a1','c2',15],
                   ['a1','c3',20],
                   ['a1','c1',15],
                   ['a2','c2',20],
                   ['a2','c3',15],
                   ['a2','c1',20],
                   ['a2','c2',15],
                   ['a3','c3',20],
                   ['a3','c3',15],
                   ['a3','c3',15],
                   ['a3','c3',20]], columns=['aid','cid','T'])

df_dummies = pd.get_dummies(df, columns=['aid','cid'],prefix_sep='',prefix='')
df_dummies

X = df_dummies
y = df_dummies['T']

# train test split 80-20
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)

regr = LinearRegression()
regr.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_pred = regr.predict(X_test)
print('R-squared:', metrics.r2_score(y_test, y_pred))
print('MAE:', metrics.mean_absolute_error(y_test, y_pred))

# Baseline model with group average as prediction
y_pred = df.groupby('aid').agg({'T': ['mean']})
print('R-squared:', metrics.r2_score(y_test, y_pred))
print('MAE:', metrics.mean_absolute_error(y_test, y_pred))

# Baseline model with group min as prediction
y_pred = df.groupby('aid').agg({'T': ['min']})
print('R-squared:', metrics.r2_score(y_test, y_pred))
print('MAE:', metrics.mean_absolute_error(y_test, y_pred))
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would rename `y_pred`all the time to not get confused.

In general:

```
y_pred = df.groupby('aid').agg({'T': ['mean']})
```

will give you the mean of the column 'aid'.

And `y_pred = df.groupby('aid').agg({'T': ['min']})` will give you the minimum.

There is an interessting package for you: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.dummy.DummyRegressor.html

This is helpful for dummy regression and has also other methods inside.

In your case it should work like this:

```
df_dummies = pd.get_dummies(df, columns=['aid','cid'],prefix_sep='',prefix='')
X = df_dummies
y = df['T']
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)
dummy_min=DummyRegressor(strategy='constant',constant=min_value)
dummy_min.fit(X_train,y_train)
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. I checked out sklearn's dummyregressor. The only way I could think to use it was  via the constant method as the mean would average all values regardless of group. So I tried 'min_value=df.groupby('aid').agg({'T':['min']})' then 'dummy_min=DummyRegressor(strategy='constant',constant=min_value)' and finally 'dummy_min.fit(X_train,y_train)' and I get a 'ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (1,3) into shape (3,1)'

Comment: what are your input features X , and what are your output feature?

Comment: the a's & c's to predict T my dataset is larger and it is a collection of runner performances so a's are athlete ids and the c's are course ids and T is the time recorded for that athlete in that performance. Regression results in a coeff for every runner and course with the lower coeff for a signifying faster runner and higher coeff for c toughest course. I want to compare my results to what the results would be if you just looked at an athlete's fastest time or their average time

Comment: Thanks PV8. Your code works to fit the dummy regressor. However when I want to get the r2 and using the original example I define y_pred=dummy_min.predict(X_test) I still get the 'ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (1,3) into shape (3,1)'  the code makes sense to me and I'm not sure what I'm doing incorrectly.